# In shinydashboard how to maintain on the same tabItem panel after click on refresh button

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

This is my shinydashboard code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = p("Title")),
                    
                    dashboardSidebar(skin = 'light',
                                     collapsed = TRUE,
                                     tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.content-wrapper { height: 1500px !important;}'))),
                                     sidebarMenu( id = "sidebarMenu",
                                                  menuItem(text = p(style = 'sidebar_menu_li',"Screen 1", style = "font-size: 1.25em;"), tabName = "panel_1"),
                                                  menuItem(text = p(style = 'sidebar_menu_li',"Screen 2", style = "font-size: 1.25em;"), tabName = "panel_2"),
                                                  menuItem(text = p(style = 'sidebar_menu_li',"Screen 3", style = "font-size: 1.25em;"), tabName = "panel_3"),
                                                  menuItem(text = p(style = 'sidebar_menu_li',"Screen 4", style = "font-size: 1.25em;"), tabName = "panel_4"))
                    ),
                    
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "panel_1" ,h1("Title 1")),
                        tabItem(tabName = 'panel_2',h1("Title 2")),
                        tabItem(tabName = 'panel_3',h1("Title 3")), 
                        tabItem(tabName = "panel_4",h1("Title 4"),
                                actionButton("submit1" ,"Submit", icon("refresh"),
                                             class = "btn btn-primary")))
                      
                    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$submit1, {
    session$reload()})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Once I click on Submit button on Screen/TabItem 4 I would like to saty on this Screen (Screen) 4, instead once I click on refresh button I come back to the Screen 1.

Any help?

Comment: Are you tied to ```session$reload```? Since it's effectively like hitting the refresh button on a browser, it's always going to start with the default, page 1. The only way I can think of to ```session$reload``` and still have the person stay on the last page, would be to do some sort of global save of their tab, then when they load back in it checks for that global thing and redirects to the last page. It might be simpler to use something like ```shinyjs()``` and use ```reset```.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Silentdevildoll . I don’t need to use session$reload. But it’s how Iam trying. And it’s not work because of what you said, it’s starting with the default page. And I would like to stay on the actual page, page 4.

Comment: I saw some answers with Shinyjs but wasn’t for specifics pages. It was related to complete dashboard itself. I think the challenger here is to know how to speechify in the code only the page that I want to refresh

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since it sounds like `shinyjs::reset()` can work for you, I used your code to show an example of how it would work, refreshing several inputs in one page. You can individually reset inputs, or if you wrap a whole page in a `div`, you can `reset` multiple items at once. To test it, just put some random text in the `textInput()` found on panel 4, then press the submit button, and they should all return to their default empty value. Hopefully this helps you proceed, good luck!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = p("Title")),
                    
                    dashboardSidebar(skin = 'light',
                                     collapsed = TRUE,
                                     tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.content-wrapper { height: 1500px !important;}'))),
                                     sidebarMenu( id = "sidebarMenu",
                                                  menuItem(text = p(style = 'sidebar_menu_li',"Screen 1", style = "font-size: 1.25em;"), tabName = "panel_1"),
                                                  menuItem(text = p(style = 'sidebar_menu_li',"Screen 2", style = "font-size: 1.25em;"), tabName = "panel_2"),
                                                  menuItem(text = p(style = 'sidebar_menu_li',"Screen 3", style = "font-size: 1.25em;"), tabName = "panel_3"),
                                                  menuItem(text = p(style = 'sidebar_menu_li',"Screen 4", style = "font-size: 1.25em;"), tabName = "panel_4"))
                    ),
                    
                    dashboardBody(
                      useShinyjs(), #Need this for shinyjs to work
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "panel_1" ,h1("Title 1")),
                        tabItem(tabName = 'panel_2',h1("Title 2")),
                        tabItem(tabName = 'panel_3',h1("Title 3")), 
                        tabItem(tabName = "panel_4",h1("Title 4"),
                                div(id = "text_reset", #Wrapping the text inputs in a div, to reset all of them at once
                                textInput("text_1", "Text_1"), #Added some text inputs to demonstrate shinyjs reset
                                textInput("text_2", "Text_2"),
                                textInput("text_3", "Text_3"),
                                textInput("text_4", "Text_4")
                                ),
                                actionButton("submit1" ,"Submit", icon("refresh"),
                                             class = "btn btn-primary")))
                      
                    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$submit1, {
    shinyjs::reset("text_reset") #Using reset instead of session$reload
    # session$reload()
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```